# sort columns and rows of a (adjacency) matrix to be upper triangular

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, directed-acyclic-graphs, adjacency-matrix

for a directed graph, I have a constraint which is the adjacency matrix `A` should be upper triangular with 0 diagonal (assert acyclic condition). Now suppose I arbitrarily have permuted the order of the nodes, so that the new adjacency matrix `B` is not upper triangular anymore. What I want is to recover `A` the triangular matrix from `B`. I can have the matrix as a `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` object so I'm looking for a solution in these libraries.

So far my solution is as follows:

1. we know that there is a node which has no parents (one all-zero column) so I find it, store it in an array, and remove the connection from other nodes
2. I repeat for all the nodes until I make the ordered list of the nodes.

here is the code:

```
def sort_nodes(adj_matrix: np.ndarray = None):
    ordered_list = []
    covered_nodes = 0
    while covered_nodes < adj_matrix.shape[0]:
        # sum of the columns
        sum_c = adj_matrix.sum(axis=0)
        # find nodes with no parents: sum should be zero
        parent_inds = list(np.where(sum_c == 0)[0])

        # an assertion to make sure the matrix can be sorted triangular
        assert len(parent_inds) != 0
        
        # update the while condition
        covered_nodes += len(parent_inds)
        # add to the list
        ordered_list += parent_inds

        # remove parent edges by set the corresponding row to zero
        adj_matrix[parent_inds, :] = 0
        # eliminate from columns by assigning values so that its sum cannot be zero
        adj_matrix[:, parent_inds] = 10
    return ordered_list
```

is there any solution to that? a function or a more concise algorithm. I also scratched the surface of graph libraries such as `networkx` but found nothing... Cheers!

#### **EDIT:1**

An example of such problem is:

```
A:
   1  2  3  4
1[[0, 1, 1, 1]
2 [0, 0, 1, 1]
3 [0, 0, 0, 1]
4 [0, 0, 0, 0]]

B:
   2  1  4  3
2[[0, 0, 1, 1]
1 [1, 0, 1, 1]
4 [0, 0, 0, 0]
3 [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

where A is a the complete sequential DAG. (fully connected as much as the acyclic condition allows)

Comment: can we assume that the non-zero values are all 1? or the graph is weighted?

Comment: @AminGheibi yes we can. elements are binary

Comment: what you have implemented is called Topological sort (it works because the graph is acyclic). You can easily implement this on a DataFrame by a for loop and ```sum``` on columns (same approach that you had). I am thinking if there is a way to implement it without for loop in pandas. I doubt it because you have to update connections of nodes and repeat.

Comment: @AminGheibi had not heard the keyword 'topological sort' before. thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: Please provide an example of a permuted matrix. Can any row consist of all 0s?

Comment: @DYZ Please see the Edit 1. And yes by concept one row and one column is always zero. because in a DAG we have at least one node with no parent and one node with no child

Answer (score 0):

For my `pandas` solution to work, add a column of all 1s to the dataframe (to avoid the all-zeros row):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0]])
df.loc[:, df.shape[1]] = 1
```

Now you can find the index of the leftmost 1 in each row. The smaller is the index, the higher was the row in the original, non-permuted matrix. Finally, sort the rows by that position and remove the last column of 1s:

```
df = df.reindex(df.idxmax(1) - 1).iloc[:,:-1]
#   0  1  2  3
#0  0  1  1  0
#2  0  0  1  1
#1  0  0  0  1
#3  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I have not quite got your idea, but just I checked it on my example (B matrix in the question) and it returned `[[1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0], [NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN], [0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0], [1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0]]` have you tested it on my example?

Comment: The dataframe must have indexes and columns 0 through N-1, not 1 through N, as it is customary in pandas (and numpy). I supplied an example that is very similar to yours.